# Can we Alter the Size of a Warehouse in Snowflake through an open query through SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2016, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just wanted to know if we can Alter the Size of a Warehouse in Snowflake through an open query using SQL Server.
I do have linked server from SQL to Snowflake created. I am able to do a normal select from SQL Server to Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the size of the warehouse using SQL:
alter warehouse my_wh set warehouse_size=medium;
Details [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-warehouse.html#alter-warehouse)

Given you have the access privileges to operate the warehouse. Details [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#virtual-warehouse-privileges)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear with my Question. I wanted to know if we can Alter the warehouse in Snowflake from SQL Server over the linked server. Access shouldn't be an issue

Comment: If you are able to issue a SQL command from SQL Server to Snowflake through a linked server, then you can issue the `ALTER WAREHOUSE` command to alter the warehouse.

Comment: I did try that through an open query from SQL Server to Snowflake. The command is reaching Snowflake but getting an error regarding permissions. Where as the account I am using has highest level privileges.

Comment: OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServerName" returned message "SQL compilation error:
Warehouse 'WarehouseName' does not exist or not authorized.".

Comment: It error points out that you might not have the permission to operate(re-size) the warehouse. Can you please check if you have the OPERATE privilege on the warehouse?